# What means Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT when sending mails with Zend_Mail?

Tags: email, zend-framework

In the example for Zend_Mail on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html they use ENCODING_8BIT but searching for what that might be sends me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526992%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx were (and this sounds logical to me) it is explained that 8bit encoding does not make sense for emails.

*Edit:*

When I use this encoding for a mail with an attachment, I receive the mail with a corrupted attachment in my mail software (Thunderbird)

In which cases does it make sense to use ENCODING_8BIT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everybody said, ENCODING_8BIT represents the **Content Transfer Encoding**.
Basically, [8BITMIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP) is used for *Internationalization*. It's using a 8-bit character sets and therefore, allow you to send any character supported in the UTF8 charset.

> In general, non-MIME mailers send 8-bit data but do not include any
> MIME headers to mark the message as 8-bit data. MIME mailers should
> cope with this without any problems. [[source]](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/HANDBOOK/RN_mail_8bit.html)

So basically there is not really a case where it makes sense to use ENCODING_8BIT over another encoding since **emails in UTF8 are a standard today**. Also, note that most of the MTAs (*Message Transfer Agent*, such as Postfix, etc.) automatically force the encoding to 8BITMIME (UTF-8).

[Here is a good resource](http://cr.yp.to/smtp/8bitmime.html) about the 8BITMIME encoding.

> The 8BITMIME extension has two effects in practice:
>
> - The client will avoid Q-P conversion.
> - The client may add extra
>   information at the end of a MAIL request: a space followed by either
>   "BODY=7BIT" or "BODY=8BITMIME".

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT` sets the [**Content-Transfer-Encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding).
The Content-Transfer-Encoding defines methods for representing binary data in ASCII text format.
The use of `Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT` in the [example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.mail.attachments.html) is a [Bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9094).

For sending Attachments you should always use `Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64`

Comment: Yes but as written below this leads to a mail with corrupted attachment. So what is the practical use for this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Not for email but for attachements. If you take a look on the RFC 2045 at page 7:

[RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-7)

> "Binary data" refers to data where any
> sequence of octets whatsoever    is
> allowed.

Comment: Mh, the RFC is not much clearer. I attached a binary file (800 KB) as 8bit and it seems to corrupt the file. I am using base64 now instead. I am still confused about what would be the practical use case for 8bit?